# Creating a random "left" position every time this animation loops

Tags: jquery

I have an animation of some parachutes that I'd like to add some random to. Each time it loops (using jquery timer plugin), I'd like to basically have it run from a random left position.

I can create my random number with the following function

```
function randomLeft() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
return randomNumber+'%';
}
```

And I have my loop:

```
$('#parachute_wrap img').everyTime ( 11, function (){
          $('#parachute_wrap img')
          .animate({top:"1000px"},25000)
          .animate({top:"-100px"});
});
```

I tried doing the following:

```
$('#parachute_wrap img').everyTime ( 11, function (){
          $('#parachute_wrap img')
          .animate({top:"1000px"},25000)
          .animate({top:"-100px", left: randomLeft()});
});
```

But it looks like it doesn't like when I just throw a function in as a value.

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/jRmUc/) with your syntax. Are you sure it is not the function .everyTime() that breaks the code ?

Comment: It is possible that everyTime is breaking the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:-

```
$('#parachute_wrap img').everyTime ( 11, function (){
          $('#parachute_wrap img')
          .animate({top:"1000px"},25000)
          .animate({top:"-100px", left: Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + '%'});
});
```

**OR**

```
$('#parachute_wrap img').everyTime ( 11, function (){
          $('#parachute_wrap img')
          .animate({top:"1000px"},25000)
          .animate({top:"-100px", left: Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 'px'});
});
```

Comment: Why would I try that... its too simple for my over complex reaching mind :( omg. it worked. ahhh... thank you!!!!